# Any reason why Magento has chosen not to compress images?

Tags: magento-1, image, htaccess, apache

There is a particular line in htaccess where compressing images are disabled:

```
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

I would like to turn image compression on but I'm looking if there's a reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Images usually have a high entropy (information per bit) making them pretty bad aspirants for compression. Compression **may** reduce their file size by e.g. ~10% but that comes at the cost of processing power on both server and client side – for *each* request of a file if this is done by a webserver that doesn't implement proper caching. Many image formats including JPEG already implement their own complex compression algorithms – lossless or lossy – thereby increasing entropy, so that any external compression might gain even less up to none reduction.